# How to get "Use Default" value by programatically?

Tags: magento

1. Switch the store
2. System->Configuration->General->Locale Options->Time zone
3. In right side `Use Default` checkout box available. One of checkbox field name is `general_locale_timezone_inherit`.
4. I want to get value, whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Mage::getStoreConfig("general/locale/timezone");
```

You can use website_code to get a website specific field value.

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('websites/[website_code]/section/group/field');
```

OR

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $storeId);
```

Comment: I want to get "Use Default" check bock value for website specific.